# edit my .txt doc using VBS

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript, I would like to update a text file with new data and have it shown in a message box.

Below is what I have so far; what am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit 
Dim oFso, Michael, John, Valery, Susane, Katterina
Dim oStream, oFolder, f, myArrayList

Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

Set myArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")  
    myArrayList.Add "Misko, Janko, Vierka,"

'create '
Call WriteLineToFile

Function WriteLineToFile
    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set f = oFso.CreateTextFile("D:\TestFile1.txt", 2, True)

    f.WriteLine "Misko, Janko, Vierka,"

    MsgBox "Subor C:\TestFile.txt bol " & "vytvoreny."

    f.Close

    Set f = Nothing
    Set oFso = Nothing

    MsgBox "Uspesne vytvoreny " & TestFile2.txt & "."   
End Function
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: What is the line `MsgBox "Uspesne vytvoreny " & TestFile2.txt & "."` supposed to do?

Comment: Update a text file? You should use [OpenTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) instead of CreateTextFile.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit 'explicit declaration of all variables'
```

`Dim oFso, f, sPath, sPath2, i, sTemp 'deklaracia'
Dim arrString`

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
```

`sPath = "D:\TestFile1.txt"     'cesta ku datam'
sPath2 = "D:\TestFile2.txt"`

`arrString = Array("Marek", "Tomas") 'pole alebo polia'
ReDim arrString(2)
arrString(0) = "Misko"
arrString(1) = "Janko"
arrString(2) = "Vierka"`

```
sTemp = ""      'empty pole pred runom'
```

`For i = 0 To UBound(arrString)             'ide po upper bound '
        If i = UBound(arrString) Then
        sTemp = sTemp + arrString(i)    'odstrani ciarku na konci'
    Else
        sTemp = sTemp + arrString(i) + ", "
    End If
Next
        MsgBox sTemp`

Answer (score 0):

```
Call WriteLineToFile (sPath, sTemp)         'zavola sub routine'
```

`ReDim Preserve arrString (4)
arrString(3) = "Zuzka"
arrString(4) = "Katka"`

```
sTemp = ""
```

`For i = 0 To UBound(arrString)
    If i = UBound(arrString) Then
        sTemp = sTemp + arrString(i)
    Else
        sTemp = sTemp + arrString(i) + ", "
    End If

Next
        MsgBox sTemp`

`Call WriteLineToFile (sPath2, sTemp)`

```
Sub WriteLineToFile (sFilePath, sText)      
    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set f = oFso.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, 2, True)
    'For i = 0 To UBound(arrString) - 1         'nepotrebne'
        f.WriteLine sText
    'Next
        MsgBox "Subor " & sFilePath & " vytvoreny."
```

`f.Close
        Set f = Nothing
        Set oFso = Nothing
End Sub`